# Retrieve a uniform data sample from a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to do some analysis on data stored in a SQL table in an external application. However, there is simply too much data to retrieve all of the relevant rows.

I'm trying to get around this by only fetching a small, uniform sample of the data.

Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this?

Comment: i guess you forgot that 'this'..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [TABLESAMPLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189108%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), e.g.

```
select * from [yourtable] tablesample(10 percent)
```

Comment: This isn't perfect, as it seems like it's uniform sampling over pages as opposed to uniform sampling over rows. But unless there's a way to guarantee row-level sampling without the cost of a table scan, this is probably my best option. Thanks much.