# Using TSQL to select a percentage of the total sum of records at random

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table that contains Road reference numbers and road length, with columns `RoadID (int)` and `RoadLength (int)`.

There are around 3000 rows. Using T-SQL I need to extract a random selection of road references and their length where the sum of the length adds up to 5% of the total length of all the roads in the table. This is for an annual road survey where roads are selected at random.

I'm using T-SQL against a SQL Server 2008 database. Tried a few variations on triangular queries from this article http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic793008-149-1.aspx but struggling with selecting random rows. I tried using `order by newID()` but my results don't look correct.

Any help with the most efficient way to do this would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: When using Order By NewID why don't the results look correct? Can you provide an example?

Comment: I adapted this useful code from http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic793008-149-1.aspx but my running total and RoadLength columns don't seem to tally. Am I using Order by NEWID() in the wrong place? I am using the following:

Comment: WITH Q (RoadID, RoadLength, ROW_NUM)
  AS 
  
   (SELECT RoadID, RoadLength, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID())
   FROM zt_Roads),
  
   RunningTotal (RoadID, RoadLength, ROW_NUM, RunningTotal) 
  
   AS 
    (SELECT *, RunningTotal = (SELECT SUM(RoadLength) FROM Q WHERE ROW_NUM <= A.ROW_NUM)
    FROM Q AS A)
     
  SELECT * FROM RunningTotal
   
  WHERE ROW_NUM <= (SELECT MIN(ROW_NUM) 
  FROM RunningTotal
 
 WHERE RunningTotal > 6000)  --test using 6000, ideally would like to use a parameter here to calculate 5% to total length

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230539/retrieve-a-uniform-data-sample-from-a-table/15230693#15230693 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848872/select-n-random-rows-from-sql-server-table

Comment: have you tried tablesample (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189108(v=sql.105).aspx) in the from clause for your random sample?  If you need exactly 5% or 10% or whatever of the total, this will not work, but it should get you the randomization you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how close to 5% of the total you need to be, but this should get you pretty close:

```
CREATE TABLE #RoadReference (RoadID INT IDENTITY, RoadLength INT)

INSERT #RoadReference (RoadLength) VALUES (CAST(RAND() * 1000 AS INT))
GO 3000

DECLARE @SampleDistance int

SELECT @SampleDistance = SUM(RoadLength) * .05 FROM #RoadReference

SELECT @SampleDistance AS FivePercentOfTotalRoadLength

SELECT RoadID, SUM(RoadLength) RoadLength
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 5 PERCENT * 
    FROM #RoadReference ORDER BY NEWID()) DataSample
GROUP BY RoadID WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY RoadLength
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Crosan, much appreciated. I tried a few versions and selected the random records okay but struggled to get a random selection where the total length adds up to 5% of all roads in the table. I've come up with a bit of a messy solution, but it seems to work…

Answer (score 0):

Messy, but it seems to work

```
--Create a temp table and add a random number column
CREATE TABLE #Roads(ROW_NUM int, RoadID int, RoadLength int)

--Populate from zt_Roads table and add a random number field
INSERT #Roads (ROW_NUM , RoadID , RoadLength )
                    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()),
                        RoadID,
                        RoadLength
                         from zt_Roads)
go

--Calcualte 5% of the TOTAL length of ALL roads
declare @FivePercent int
SELECT  @FivePercent =  ROUND(Sum(IsNULL((RoadLength ),0))*.01,0) from zt_Roads
print 'One Percent of total length = ' 
Print @FivePercent

--Select a random sample from temp table so that the total sample length 
--is no more than 5% of all roads in table
; with RandomSample as 
(SELECT top 100 percent 
    ROW_NUM, 
    RoadID, 
    RoadLength, 
    RoadLength+
        COALESCE((Select Sum(RoadLength) from #Roads b 
        WHERE b.ROW_NUM < a.ROW_NUM),0) as RunningTotal

        From #Roads  a
        ORDER BY ROW_NUM)


Select * from RandomSample WHERE RunningTotal <@FivePercent 
Drop table #Roads
```